# How to search via textbox in custom databasegridview vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, visual-studio-2019

I made a datagridview with joined columns from different tables.

The code I used for this is here:

```
    Private Sub Dossiers_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\GoogleDrive\EINDWERK VBNET\PatientenDatabase.accdb"
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection(str)
        Dim com As String = "Select          tbl_Dossiers.Dos_ID, tbl_Relaties.Rel_Naam, tbl_Relaties.Rel_Voornaam, tbl_Onderzoekstypes.OZ_TypeOnderzoek, tbl_Diagnoses.Diag_Type
                               FROM((((tbl_Dossiers 
                               Left OUTER JOIN tbl_DossRelatie ON tbl_Dossiers.Dos_ID = tbl_DossRelatie.DR_DossID) 
                               Left OUTER JOIN tbl_Relaties ON tbl_DossRelatie.DR_RelID = tbl_Relaties.Rel_ID) 
                               Left OUTER JOIN tbl_OnderzoeksTypes ON tbl_Dossiers.OZ_ID = tbl_OnderzoeksTypes.OZ_ID) 
                               Left OUTER JOIN tbl_Diagnoses ON tbl_Dossiers.Diag_ID = tbl_Diagnoses.Diag_ID)
                               ORDER BY        tbl_Dossiers.Dos_ID"
        Dim adpt As New OleDbDataAdapter(com, con)
        Dim dossierset As New DataSet()
        adpt.Fill(dossierset, "Dos_ID")
        Dim DossierbindingSource As New BindingSource
        DGVDossiers.DataSource = dossierset.Tables(0)
        dgvDossiers.Show()
```

Now i've created textboxes to filter this datagridview in order to search very specifically for the right dossier in that view in order to open and edit it in a new form.

In a single table datagridview i can simply use code like this:

```
Private Sub txtSearchRelation_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtSearchRelation.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            Tbl_RelatiesBindingSource.Filter = "Rel_Naam like '" & txtSearchRelation.Text & "%'" &
                " OR Rel_Voornaam like '" & txtSearchRelation.Text & "%'"
            'NOG VERDER AAN TE VULLEN MET ANDERE FILTERS!!!!
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub BtnZoekRelatie_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnZoekRelatie.Click
        Tbl_RelatiesBindingSource.Filter = "Rel_Naam like '" & txtSearchRelation.Text & "%'" &
                " OR Rel_Voornaam like '" & txtSearchRelation.Text & "%'"
    End Sub
```

But for the life of me i can't make it work in that joined tbl datagridview.
Anyone has an idea on how to fix this?
I'm trying to search via enterkey on the textbox and via searchbutton next to the textbox
i'm a beginner.

Comment: What is the relation between `Tbl_RelatiesBindingSource` (which appears out of nowhere), `DossierbindingSource` (which you never set to anything) and `dossierset.Tables(0)`? Why do you fill a DataSet when you discard it right after to just use the first DataTable? What is `dgvDossiers` (same name as the `DGVDossiers` DataGridView)? Is that a Form? If so name it, e.g., `frmDossiers`. It appears you're using the default instance of this Form(?). Careful with that.

Comment: @Jimi: I have no idea what to do so i've been trying out stuff.
The code there works to show me the dossiers with the correct data in them.
How did i discard?
dgv = datagridview, there's no form besides the form with that datagridview on it
this is my view in vs2019: https://imgur.com/oHOPMIq
this is how it looks when i start it : https://imgur.com/YvDoKMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to filter DataGridView, you can try the following code.

```
TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[{0}] = '{1}'", columnName, filterValue)
```

So for your question,it looks liks

```
Private Sub txtSearchRelation_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtSearchRelation.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        TryCast(DGVDossiers.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Rel_Naam like '" & txtSearchRelation.Text & "%'" &
            " OR Rel_Voornaam like '" & txtSearchRelation.Text & "%'"           
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

made this:

```
   Private Sub Pat_VoornaamTextBox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Pat_VoornaamTextBox.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            TryCast(DGVDossiers.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Rel_Naam LIKE '" & Pat_VoornaamTextBox.Text & "%'" &
            " OR Rel_Voornaam like '" & Pat_VoornaamTextBox.Text & "%'"
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub zoekNaam_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles zoekNaam.Click
        If Pat_VoornaamTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Vul iets in", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            TryCast(DGVDossiers.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Rel_Naam LIKE '" & Pat_VoornaamTextBox.Text & "%'" &
            " OR Rel_Voornaam like '" & Pat_VoornaamTextBox.Text & "%'"
        End If

    End Sub
```